# Get Order list from Woocommerce REST API for today date(As default)

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, woocommerce

I am using Woocmmerce REST API to make our *Vue* dashboard. So as a feature, I am trying to list today orders and this month orders.
I knew that *WooCommerce* has date filters like after and before.

But actually I need to set the date as a default(which means current date), so my client can view today orders at the end of the day(daily).
*WooCommerce* usual timestamp is like this `2020-09-17T10:56:17`. I could not match this one with the current day and time from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`, so I can retrieve today orders.

My code goes like this…
I have just tried to make the time and date modification like below, I knew its a silly one as I am a fresher in *Vue*.

```
methods: {
    // Extract refresh logic into a method
    refreshData () {
        const today = new Date();
        const date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
        const setStartTime = "00" + ":" + "00" + ":" + "00";
        const setCloseTime = "23" + ":" + "59" + ":" + "59";
     
        // Set start time
        const startCombineDateAndTime = date + 'T' + setStartTime; 
        //this.currenttime = dateTime;
        console.log("start" + startCombineDateAndTime);
     
        // Set close time
        const closeCombineDateAndTime = date + 'T' + setCloseTime; 
        //this.currenttime = dateTime;
        console.log("close" + closeCombineDateAndTime);

        axios.get('https://testing.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?after=startCombineDateAndTime&before=closeCombineDateAndTime&per_page=40&consumer_key=ck_123&consumer_secret=cs_456')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not applying your timestamps correctly in your axios call. You can use JS' template string syntax to expand the values in order to call the correct URL:

```
axios.get(`https://testing.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?after=${startCombineDateAndTime}&before=${closeCombineDateAndTime}&per_page=40&consumer_key=ck_123&consumer_secret=cs_456`)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, still i get 400 error and not getting the orders list. Woocommerce usual time stamp is like this "2020-09-17T10:56:17"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it through fixing the axios.get url and convertingJS timestamp to  ISO8601 compliant date. If anyone needs...

```
var today= new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var isoTimeType = today.toISOString();
   
    axios.get('https:/testing.de/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?per_page=40&consumer_key=ck_123&consumer_secret=cs_456', {
        params: {
            after: isoTimeType 
        }
    })
```